# How to deal with nested XML structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following nested XML structure

```
<forum>
   <title>Title1</title>
   <id>123</id>
   <forum>
       <title>Title1b</title>
       <id>123b</id>
   </forum>
</forum>
<forum>
   <title>Title2</title>
   <id>321</id>
</forum>
<forum>
   <title>Title3</title>
   <id>456</id>
</forum>
```

As you can see in the above structure, I have a nested "forum" tag in the first element but not in the second and third.  I have tried running a if `getElementsByTagName("forum").item(0).text` on the parent nodes, but it throws an error for the second and third parent nodes because the child node for "forum" doesn't actually exist.

How could I properly check to see if those child nodes exist and then act on them?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the `innerText` method nor did you identify the parent element. Also, getElementsByTagName returns an array. My example works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/M2F64/2/

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  Is it possible to only output the parent items and not the child element of the first set?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not an array. Using `item(X)` is fine...